# LM2623 Regulator

Tags: dc-dc-converter, component-selection, switching, texas-instruments, switching-regulator

I'm implementing a DC/DC regulator and you can find the datasheet in this [link](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1896184.pdf).

What I'm trying to do it's basically reproduce the application note in order to have Vin = 12V and Vout = 5V 1Amp but I'm not understanding how do I choose the inductor. They are saying the value for the inductor is 4,7uH but it seems very subjective.

My very first problem is how do I choose the inductor if I don't know which frequency should I select. It seems I can choose something between (300 kHz to 2 MHz) but how do I know which frequency is the best for my case?

Not only that, for the typical application circuit they have put in the datasheet (pag.1) they have a 2 cells for the Vin which I thinks it's something around 7,4V.

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [great load](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/power-management/step-down-buck-converter-products.page?#p1129=Buck&p32=1;1&p238max=11;95&p634min=0.6;5&p634max=5;85&p451max=1;30) of TI's buck converters.

You can consider this [one](http://www.ti.com/product/lmr12010) for example.

- Input voltage range of 3V to 20V
- Output voltage range of 0.8V to 17V
- Output current up to 1A

and the best part for you is the Featured tools and software tab where you can define your parameters and this [tool](http://webench.ti.com/webench5/power/webench5.cgi?base_pn=LMR12010X&Flavor=NA&AppType=None&topology=&optFactor=3&VinMin=12&VinMax=12&O1I=1&O1V=5&op_TA=30&application=POWER) calculates the rest for you.

[image]

In your case with [LMR12010](http://www.ti.com/product/lmr12010):

[image]

I did not do a great search, you may find a more suitable converter. It is just a demonstration of the WEBENCH tool which can help you creating your design (not available for all component).

Comment: THanks @battleHamster. I was checking that schematic and it seems ok. 
There's only a doubt for me which is related with the boost pin. How can i put 5V there if I don't have that Voltage in my design and the pin can only handle 5,5V max. Can you help on that?

Comment: I have not used this IC before so I know as much as the datasheet says. And it says on [page 10](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmr12010.pdf)that there are four ways to drive this pin. Number 3 is on the schematic above, "from an external distributed voltage rail". But depending on the datasheet you can drive it from the input or [the output voltage](http://postimg.org/image/qpqd403gx/) too. Note that, I just picked one IC from the list as an example, there can be a simplier one for your application.

Comment: [This](http://www.ti.com/product/lm2575hv#parametrics) IC could be good too, and I think you can use this [setup](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/datasheetdiagram.tsp?genericPartNumber=LM2575HV&diagramId=23410) (also from datasheet).

Comment: Indeed. You helped me a lot.

Comment: Glad to hear that. :)

Answer (score 2):

> What I'm trying to do it's basically reproduce the application note in
>   order to have Vin = 12V and Vout = 5V 1Amp

You have chosen the wrong device. The LM2623 is a boost regulator and not a buck regulator: -

[image]

If you want a buck regulator then TI have a good search engine and so do linear tech: -

[image]

Entering an input voltage range of 10V to 15V produced 6 hits for 5V at 1A

Comment: Oh Ok my bad. Thanks Andy. 
But can you recommend me one cheap and easy to implement.

Comment: Not really but if you find one I can take a look. TI have got loads and a decent parametric engine too.

Comment: @scuba if this question has been answered would you care to "accept" the most appropriate answer.